# multiline ksh command just goes to a new line

Tags: unix, ksh

I'm very new to KSH and I created a small 5 line echo code in notepad, copy and pasted it into putty, but when I hit enter, all I get is this ">", essentially a new line, for some reason, it doesn't seem to run the code. I've tried using a ".", "exit", ";", but all it gives me is a new line starting with a ">"...how do I get a multi line code to run in KSH?

here is the code:

```
testvar1=$(bteq << EOF 2>&1
    .LOGON db/user,pass
    DATABASE schema:
    SEL CURRENT_DATE;
    .LOGOFF;
    .QUIT;
    .EXIT
    EOF)
echo "The date is: " $testvar1
```

Comment: Show us the lines you are trying to run.  You probably have an unmatched quote or something which makes the shell think one line is wrapping to the next, and thus displays the line continuation character ">".  Press Ctrl-C to break out go go back to the prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the line continuation is intentional, you need to escape the carriage return by entering a backslash at the end of the line.  This takes away the special meaning of the carriage return (send the command to the shell):

```
$ echo "Hello \
> World"
Hello World
$
```

Comment: the back slash didn't seem to work...the Crtl+C helped though in getting back to the prompt...

Comment: The closing EOF of your here-document needs to start in the very first character of the line.  I am not familiar with the bteq command, so i do not know is it is syntactically correct or not.

Comment: Tip - Don't assume your bteq command worked.  Only display it's output after testing for failure using the return code from the command.